# OnPost Method not being called from JS in Razor pages

Tags: javascript, razor-pages

I am building a cart which sends the order from Js to my razor page but when i fires it, it seems to fail, even after inputing the right url path

This is my Cart.js script

```
function updateOrder(order) {

    var r = new XMLHttpRequest();

    r.open('post', '/Cart?handler=LogOrder');
    r.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    r.send(order);

    r.onload = function () {
        let res = r.responseText;

        if (r.readyState == 4 && r.status == 200) {
            alert('Your order was processed successful and will be delivered to you shortly!!!');
            window.location = '/shop'; // redirect
        }
        else {
            alert('Oops.. An error occured seems like we were unable to process your order');
        }
    }

}
```

My OnPost Razor pages CartPageModel

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostLogOrder(Order order)
    {
        if (order != null)
        {
            await orderRepo.AddOrder(order);
        }

        return RedirectToPage("Shop");
    }
```

When ever i try to save it fails